# Jquery Store result from a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am writing jquery within a php foreach loop & I want to store jquery variable result for later use. How can I do that ? Here what I am doing:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $html .='
        PerUnitPrice = parseFloat(jQuery("#PerUnitPrice'.$product->product_id.'").html());
        PerUnitQuantity = parseFloat(jQuery("#PerUnitQuantity'.$product->product_id.'").val());
        PerUnitTotal = PerUnitPrice*PerUnitQuantity;
        jQuery("#PerUnitTotal'.$product->product_id.'").html(PerUnitTotal);
        Total = PerUnitTotal;
    ';
}
```

In `Total` I want to store all the `PerUnitTotal`. How can I do that ?

Comment: You are redefining all your variables over and over, only the last product will be _defined_. Here is what your code outputs: `a=0; a=1; a=2;`. In the end, `a` will be equal to 2.

Comment: mixing php and js is always a mess and rarely a good idea. Perhaps explain exactly what you are trying to acheieve - there will be a better way.

Comment: Hey sorry. I got the solution. Just `Total = PerUnitTotal + Total;`

Comment: What I wanted to store all the perunittotal result in Total variable :)

Comment: Then, please delete that question, it will not be useful to any future visitor

Comment: For future reference, you were writing *Javascript*, jQuery is just a Javascript library